GRASS r.sim.water results in "ERROR: Raster not found" in QGIS. Function in GRASS standalone works. How come?
I am trying to simulate overland flow, using GRASS 7 r.sim.water in QGIS from the processing toolbox. I have a DEM raster and calculated the dx and dy derivatives using r.slope.aspect. These are the three required input data, the other inputs of r.sim.water were left default. The output layers could not be generated (and there was no simulation, given the fast output):

QGIS version: 3.28.12-Firenze QGIS code revision: dcc633b2de Qt
version: 5.15.3 Python version: 3.9.5 GDAL version: 3.7.2 GEOS
version: 3.12.0-CAPI-1.18.0 PROJ version: Rel. 9.3.0, September 1st,
2023 PDAL version: 2.5.5 (git-version: 24f78d) Algorithm started at:
2024-09-03T14:55:29 Algorithm 'r.sim.water' starting… Input
parameters: { '-t' : False, 'GRASS_MIN_AREA_PARAMETER' : 0.0001,
'GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER' : 0, 'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_META' : '',
'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_OPT' : '', 'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER' : 0,
'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : None, 'GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER' :
-1, 'GRASS_VECTOR_DSCO' : '', 'GRASS_VECTOR_EXPORT_NOCAT' : False, 'GRASS_VECTOR_LCO' : '', 'depth' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT',
'diffusion_coeff' : 0.8, 'discharge' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'dx' :
'C:/Users/M0266/Desktop/FloodMap/dx.tif', 'dy' :
'C:/Users/M0266/Desktop/FloodMap/dy.tif', 'elevation' :
'C:/Users/M0266/Desktop/FloodMap/DSM_POST.tif', 'error' :
'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'flow_control' : None, 'halpha' : 4, 'hbeta' :
0.5, 'hmax' : 4, 'infil' : None, 'infil_value' : 0, 'logfile' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'man' : None, 'man_value' : 0.1, 'niterations' :
10, 'nwalkers' : None, 'observation' : None, 'output_step' : 2, 'rain'
: None, 'rain_value' : 50, 'walkers_output' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT' }
g.proj -c
wkt="C:/Users/M0266/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_ksdUuj/5f52222bd1c345a887ba50a180738445/crs.prj"
r.in.gdal input="C:\Users\M0266\Desktop\FloodMap\DSM_POST.tif" band=1
output="rast_66d70741db4a911" --overwrite -o r.in.gdal
input="C:\Users\M0266\Desktop\FloodMap\dx.tif" band=1
output="rast_66d70741dbd9912" --overwrite -o r.in.gdal
input="C:\Users\M0266\Desktop\FloodMap\dy.tif" band=1
output="rast_66d70741dbd9913" --overwrite -o g.region n=189804.0
s=188869.0 e=128185.0 w=127287.0 res=1.0 r.sim.water
elevation=rast_66d70741db4a911 dx=rast_66d70741dbd9912
dy=rast_66d70741dbd9913 rain_value=50 infil_value=0 man_value=0.1
niterations=10 output_step=2 diffusion_coeff=0.8 hmax=4 halpha=4
hbeta=0.5 depth=depthd264594fe52e470c863280726a5c6393
discharge=discharged264594fe52e470c863280726a5c6393
error=errord264594fe52e470c863280726a5c6393
walkers_output=walkers_outputd264594fe52e470c863280726a5c6393
logfile="C:/Users/M0266/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_ksdUuj/6130bddb12e849a7a66a4874fd346c18/logfile.txt"
--overwrite g.region raster=depthd264594fe52e470c863280726a5c6393 r.out.gdal -t -m input="depthd264594fe52e470c863280726a5c6393"
output="C:\Users\M0266\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_ksdUuj\88a6c9c99fba43f681f7afaae3dbd728\depth.tif"
format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite g.region
raster=discharged264594fe52e470c863280726a5c6393 r.out.gdal -t -m
input="discharged264594fe52e470c863280726a5c6393"
output="C:\Users\M0266\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_ksdUuj\e5a4df71b3d24c88a233d147b66a660f\discharge.tif"
format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite g.region
raster=errord264594fe52e470c863280726a5c6393 r.out.gdal -t -m
input="errord264594fe52e470c863280726a5c6393"
output="C:\Users\M0266\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_ksdUuj\7fe06e57fa8f49d89d27327d872a387c\error.tif"
format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite v.out.ogr
type="auto" input="walkers_outputd264594fe52e470c863280726a5c6393"
output="C:\Users\M0266\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_ksdUuj\520534e17060420883df9333138029d3\walkers_output.gpkg"
format="GPKG" --overwrite WARNING: Concurrent mapset locking is not
supported on Windows C:\Windows\System32>chcp 1252 1>NUL
C:\Windows\System32>g.proj -c
wkt="C:/Users/M0266/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_ksdUuj/5f52222bd1c345a887ba50a180738445/crs.prj"
Default region was updated to the new projection, but if you have
multiple mapsets g.region -d should be run in each to update the
region from the default Projection information updated
C:\Windows\System32>r.in.gdal
input="C:\Users\M0266\Desktop\FloodMap\DSM_POST.tif" band=1
output="rast_66d70741db4a911" --overwrite -o Over-riding projection
check Importing raster map <rast_66d70741db4a911>...
0..3..6..9..12..15..18..21..24..27..30..33..36..39..42..45..48..51..54..57..60..63..66..69..72..75..78..81..84..87..90..93..96..99..100 C:\Windows\System32>r.in.gdal
input="C:\Users\M0266\Desktop\FloodMap\dx.tif" band=1
output="rast_66d70741dbd9912" --overwrite -o Over-riding projection
check Importing raster map <rast_66d70741dbd9912>...
0..3..6..9..12..15..18..21..24..27..30..33..36..39..42..45..48..51..54..57..60..63..66..69..72..75..78..81..84..87..90..93..96..99..100 C:\Windows\System32>r.in.gdal
input="C:\Users\M0266\Desktop\FloodMap\dy.tif" band=1
output="rast_66d70741dbd9913" --overwrite -o Over-riding projection
check Importing raster map <rast_66d70741dbd9913>...
0..3..6..9..12..15..18..21..24..27..30..33..36..39..42..45..48..51..54..57..60..63..66..69..72..75..78..81..84..87..90..93..96..99..100 C:\Windows\System32>g.region n=189804.0 s=188869.0 e=128185.0
w=127287.0 res=1.0 C:\Windows\System32>r.sim.water
elevation=rast_66d70741db4a911 dx=rast_66d70741dbd9912
dy=rast_66d70741dbd9913 rain_value=50 infil_value=0 man_value=0.1
niterations=10 output_step=2 diffusion_coeff=0.8 hmax=4 halpha=4
hbeta=0.5 depth=depthd264594fe52e470c863280726a5c6393
discharge=discharged264594fe52e470c863280726a5c6393
error=errord264594fe52e470c863280726a5c6393
walkers_output=walkers_outputd264594fe52e470c863280726a5c6393
logfile="C:/Users/M0266/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_ksdUuj/6130bddb12e849a7a66a4874fd346c18/logfile.txt"
--overwrite C:\Windows\System32>g.region raster=depthd264594fe52e470c863280726a5c6393 ERROR: Raster map
 not found
C:\Windows\System32>r.out.gdal -t -m
input="depthd264594fe52e470c863280726a5c6393"
output="C:\Users\M0266\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_ksdUuj\88a6c9c99fba43f681f7afaae3dbd728\depth.tif"
format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite ERROR:
Raster map or group  not found
C:\Windows\System32>g.region
raster=discharged264594fe52e470c863280726a5c6393 ERROR: Raster map
 not found
C:\Windows\System32>r.out.gdal -t -m
input="discharged264594fe52e470c863280726a5c6393"
output="C:\Users\M0266\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_ksdUuj\e5a4df71b3d24c88a233d147b66a660f\discharge.tif"
format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite ERROR:
Raster map or group  not
found C:\Windows\System32>g.region
raster=errord264594fe52e470c863280726a5c6393 ERROR: Raster map
 not found
C:\Windows\System32>r.out.gdal -t -m
input="errord264594fe52e470c863280726a5c6393"
output="C:\Users\M0266\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_ksdUuj\7fe06e57fa8f49d89d27327d872a387c\error.tif"
format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite ERROR:
Raster map or group  not found
C:\Windows\System32>v.out.ogr type="auto"
input="walkers_outputd264594fe52e470c863280726a5c6393"
output="C:\Users\M0266\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_ksdUuj\520534e17060420883df9333138029d3\walkers_output.gpkg"
format="GPKG" --overwrite ERROR: Vector map
<walkers_outputd264594fe52e470c863280726a5c6393> not found
C:\Windows\System32>exit Press any key to continue . . . Execution
completed in 12.97 seconds Results: {'depth':
'C:\Users\M0266\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_ksdUuj\88a6c9c99fba43f681f7afaae3dbd728\depth.tif',
'discharge':
'C:\Users\M0266\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_ksdUuj\e5a4df71b3d24c88a233d147b66a660f\discharge.tif',
'error':
'C:\Users\M0266\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_ksdUuj\7fe06e57fa8f49d89d27327d872a387c\error.tif',
'logfile':
'C:/Users/M0266/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_ksdUuj/6130bddb12e849a7a66a4874fd346c18/logfile.txt',
'walkers_output':
'C:\Users\M0266\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_ksdUuj\520534e17060420883df9333138029d3\walkers_output.gpkg'}
Loading resulting layers The following layers were not correctly
generated. •
C:/Users/M0266/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_ksdUuj/520534e17060420883df9333138029d3/walkers_output.gpkg
•
C:/Users/M0266/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_ksdUuj/7fe06e57fa8f49d89d27327d872a387c/error.tif
•
C:/Users/M0266/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_ksdUuj/88a6c9c99fba43f681f7afaae3dbd728/depth.tif
•
C:/Users/M0266/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_ksdUuj/e5a4df71b3d24c88a233d147b66a660f/discharge.tif
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find
more information about the execution of the algorithm.

This problem occurs in QGIS (3.28.12) not in the standalone GRASS (8.4.0) on MS Windows 10 x64 (simulates and produces the desired output).
Related issues here and here, but this solution is not relevant/working: setting GRASS GIS 7 region extent to the DEM extent did not resolve the issue.
